# Change inner text after ajax call back doesn't work?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have ten like buttons on a page, that I create by a foreach loop on the page.

I have problem in changing the inner text with jQuery.

Let me explain with my elements

```
     <a class="pr-endorse" id="<%=product.ConfectionaryProductId %>">
        <i class="pr-add"></i>
        <span>+</span>
        <span class="pr-likes"><%=product.EndorsementCount %></span>
    </a>
```

This one of my like button elements.

And this is the Ajax function to submit the user like

```
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".pr-endorse").click(function () {
            debugger;
            var productId = $(this).attr("id");
            var confId = $("#ConfectioneryId").val();
            var countNumber = $(this).find(".pr-likes").html();
            $.ajax({
                url: '<%: Url.Action("Endorsement","Confectionery")%>',
                data: { productId: productId, itemId: confId },
                type: "POST",
                async: true,
                cache: false,
                success: function (result) {

                    debugger;
                    $(this).find(".pr-likes").text(result.endoresCount);
                    alert(result.endoresCount);

                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    alert(xhr);
                }
```

I thing that this part of code should solve

```
  $(this).find(".pr-likes").text(result.endoresCount);
```

but it does not work ?

Comment: The question is, why would `result` be an object? There doesn't look like a dataType is set, but not all the options are visible, the function is cut off, so who knows? Also, we have no idea what the server returns, where's that code ?

Comment: Also, `this` inside the success function is not an element, it's the ajax function

Comment: @adeneo Thanks for comment , if you see result have object that name is endoesmentCount , this the int data type that return by ajax call back

Comment: But why would an ajax call return an object, it can't return anything but a string, so either jQuery is parsing it for you, which it does if you add the correct dataType or the correct serverside headers, or it's still a string

Comment: @adeneo Actulally i dont have any idea , can you help me ?

Comment: I already have, I posted an answer below ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give it a try, it should probably look like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".pr-endorse").click(function () {

        var self        = this
        var productId   = self.id;
        var confId      = $("#ConfectioneryId").val();
        var countNumber = $(this).find(".pr-likes").html();

        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url  : '<%: Url.Action("Endorsement","Confectionery")%>',
            data : {
                productId : productId,
                itemId    : confId
            },
            dataType : 'json',
            success : function (result) {

                $(self).find(".pr-likes").text(result.endoresCount);
                alert(result.endoresCount);

            },
            error : function (xhr) {
                alert(xhr);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Note that `this` inside the success function is not the element that was clicked, and to return an object you'd generally want to set the dataType, even if jQuery will parse it if the headers are correct.

Comment: Thank you very musch , it works , can you say me where  is my mistake

Comment: It's in the comments I left you, and in the answer above?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(".pr-endorse").click(function () {
    var el = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        success: function (result) {
            el.find(".pr-likes").text(result.endoresCount);
        }
    });
});
```

Also, make sure you are returning `Json(new { endoresCount = count });` from your controller.

Comment: thanks for you awnser , yes i return from controller same as you said